# What is the difference between DROP and DELETE for tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Which one will *delete* all data from the table, and which one will *remove the table* from the database?

What is the right thing to do if I do not want this table in my database any more?
Should I drop or delete the table?

Comment: It is encourage to do a little bit of search before asking a question. Considering that MySQL has a fairly extensive [reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/), there is no need to ask here. (There are more interesting questions like, is a DROP+CREATE ever better than a DELETE? But that does not apply in this case.)

Answer (score 13):

DROP command deleting the table and its structure from the data base.

```
DROP TABLE tbl_user;
```

DELETE command used for deleting the records from the table, and it removing the table space which is allocated by the data base, and  returns number of rows deleted.

```
DELETE FROM tbl_user WHERE id = 1;
```

TRUNCATE command is also delete the records but it doesn't delete the table space which is created by the data base, and does not return number of deleted rows.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tbl_user;
```

Answer (score 7):

[DROP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/drop-table.html) is used to remove tables (and databases).

[DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html) is used to delete rows from tables.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe are you talking about `TRUNCATE` and `DELETE` ?

```
TRUNCATE TABLE users;
```

is equivalent (logically) to

```
DELETE FROM users;
```

This will erase all data in table `users`. If you want to delete the whole table structure you should write:

```
DROP TABLE users;
```

But, DELETE is DML command while TRUNCATE and DROP are DDL commands. There is also some other differences in different RDBMS. More info - [here](http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/425)

And another useful link: [Difference between TRUNCATE, DELETE and DROP commands](http://orafaq.com/faq/difference_between_truncate_delete_and_drop_commands)

Answer (score 2):

[`drop`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/drop-table.html) removes the contents *and* the table (but not user permissions on the table). This is what you want if you want to completely remove the table from your schema.

[`delete`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) selectively (or not) removes rows from a table. It does not alter the table structure.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as **DELETE TABLE**. You should use **DROP TABLE** to delete your table.

Answer (score 1):

The DROP TABLE statement is used to delete a table.

> DROP TABLE table_name

The DELETE statement is used to delete data(records) in a table.

> DELETE FROM table_name WHERE some_column=some_value;

So, as you want to delete table from database then you will go for **DROP** Command

Answer (score 0):

DELETE is used to delete one or several rows from the table. DROP TABLE would remove the entire table from the database, so if you want to remove the table, you should use DROP TABLE.

[DROP TABLE reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/drop-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

Delete will update the log, while drop does not.

Delete is used to remove the rows, while drop is used to remove the tables and DB.

Answer (score 0):

**delete** 
- removes the rows from the table - where clause can be used to delete specific rows. 
- If where is not specified, then all the rows in the table will be removed 
- rollback can be done.

without using where condition

```
DELETE * FROM empl;
```

using where condition

```
DELETE FROM empl WHERE job = 'Manager';
```

**truncate** 
- removes all the rows from the table. 
- rollback cannot be done.

```
SQL> TRUNCATE TABLE empl;
```

**drop** 
- removes a table from the database. 
- rows, indexes and privileges will also be removed. 
- rollback cannot be done.

```
SQL> DROP TABLE empl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete remove all data from a specific table and drop remove whole database and also remove specific table from database.
If you don't want the table in database any more then you should drop the table.